# Using Django Templates to send an email

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I have a Django template that I'm using to send emails. I'm using Sorl thumbnail to generate a thumbnail to be used in the email.

```
{% thumbnail event.image '90x100' crop=True as im %}
    <img class="float-center"
        src="{{ im.url }}" alt="">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

The issue is the src is an absolute path on the filesystem. I would like to prepend the im.url with my server's web address. I tried a few ways of concatenating strings but nothing seemed to stick.

Comment: The problem is that the host is not included in the `url`.

Comment: Yes, I'm having issues getting the host to be sent over.